# Why assert_select is not accepting parameters rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, assertions

I am working on rails integration tests, someone wrote tests that were passing at that time but now they are giving warning

here is the line of code i was working on

```
assert_select "a[href=/monster_xml_users/#{user_xml.id}][data-method=delete]", I18n.t('revoke_access')
```

But now it is giving warning

> Invalid CSS selector, Assertion not run

But if i write it alternatively like this

```
 assert_select "a", I18n.t('revoke_access')
        assert_select "a" do
          assert_select "[href=?]","/monster_xml_users/#{user_xml.id}"
          assert_select "[data-method=?]", "delete"
        end
```

Then it gives no warning and tests pass and it is correct. 
But i am unable to figure out why previous assertion is failing now ?
Has assert_select syntax is changed now in Rails 4.2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are following the old syntax of asserting. Now rails prefer to put quotes around the css object like following

```
assert_select "a[href='/monster_xml_users/#{user_xml.id}'][data-method='delete']", I18n.t('revoke_access')
```